# Heroku Integration with pandastream

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pandastream

Just going through the heroku add-ons docs and i'm coming up with this error..

```
irb(main):001:0> Panda::Profile.all
```

NameError: uninitialized constant Panda

I've done exactly what it says, but this error is popping up when testing the local setup, thanks.

Comment: inside your irb first require "panda"

Comment: you mean just type 'require "panda"' into the heroku console

Comment: ya,but m not sure whether this will fixe your problem or not...but if u want to use any gem inside your irb u need require them inside your console.....just try running 
require "panda"

Comment: didn't work, thanks for your input though, just says, LoadError: cannot load such file -- Panda

Comment: that means your gem panda in not loaded...otherwise require "panda" either return true or false but never LoadError: cannot load such file -- Panda

Comment: I'm running the heroku console, undefined local variable or method `panda' for main:Object

Comment: it shows false in rails console, and heroku console states as above